# Why do I get a compiler warning with "int __attribute__((address(0x3000))) x;"

Tags: pic, microchip, variable

I am trying to understand why I get the following warning

```
#include <xc.h>

int main (void)
{
     int __attribute__((address(0x3000))) x;


     while(1);

     return 0;
 }
```

> PIC24_Attributes.c:13:5: warning: ignoring address attribute applied to automatic x

I know `__attribute__address((address(0x3000))) x` means store the variable of type int x in DATA SPACE address 0x3000

When I download the program, and debug it, I see that the address of x is 0x856

but when I put it globally the warning disappears, and when I debug, the address of x is 0x3000.

I googled the warning I got, and I found someone with the same warning as me, but with the space attribute instead  (http://www.microchip.com/forums/m351172.aspx)

From what I understood was `__attribute__` only works for static variables, and automatic variables (don't know why it is automatic, it is an int) are allocated dynamically.

Can someone explain this please, as I understand that `**attribute**((address(...)))' means store the following variable at a certain address.

- Microncotroller: PIC24FJ1024GB610 (Microchip)
- Debugger: PKOB (Explorer 16/32 Development Board)

Comment: I think your question is more appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: XC16 users guide section 2.5.2 Absolute Addressing: Variables and functions can be placed at an absolute address by using the __at() construct. **Stack-based (auto and parameter) variables cannot use the** __at() specifier... 16- and 32-bit compilers have used the **address attribute** to specify an object’s address.

Comment: that wouldn't have even needed reading the compiler manuals to be answered on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatic refers to the C concept of *automatic storage duration*. In C, there are chiefly 2 different **storage durations** for objects: **static** (not to be confused with the `static` keyword, which is a *storage-class specifier*) and **automatic**. An object shall retain its last stored value and will be stored at a constant address for the entire duration of its lifetime.

Static storage duration means *"the duration of the entire program"* - that is, from before entering the `main` the first time up to after exiting it.

Automatic storage duration is for objects "declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier `static`" - the *no linkage* means that they're not declared globally - they're declared/defined within a block, and not declared with storage-class specifier `extern`. Their lifetime is chiefly to the end of the block.

Now in your program,

```
#include <xc.h>
int main (void)
{
     int __attribute__((address(0x3000))) x;
     while(1);
     return 0;
}
```

Since the declaration-definition `int x;` it has neither the `extern` nor `static` *storage-class specifier*, it defines an `int` object of *automatic* storage duration within the `main` function. Each time the `main` function is entered, a *new* distinct object must be allocated. C allows the `main` function to call itself recursively too, so clearly `x` simply cannot be at a fixed address here. In fact, on many computer architectures `x` might not even reside in memory at all - it might be in a register, or optimized out completely.

---

It makes sense only to have an object that has *static* storage duration, as opposed to automatic storage duration, to be located at a fixed address. In addition to declaring this at the *file* scope:

```
int __attribute__((address(0x3000))) x;
int main(void) { ... }
```

which would make `x` accessible everywhere within the file, you can also make the identifier private to the `main` function, but still retain the *static storage duration*, by using the `static` *storage-class specifier*:

```
int main(void) { 
    static int __attribute__((address(0x3000))) x;
    ... 
}
```

Now, the identifier `x` is not visible outside the `main` function; and exactly only one `x` is defined, and its storage duration is static, which means that it is for the entire duration of the program - as its storage duration is not *automatic*, but it will have a fixed address for the entire runtime of the program, the compiler can be asked to locate it at an alternate address.

Answer (score 10):

`x` is a local variable. It doesn't necessarily even get a storage address. So, you can't necessarily assign an address to it.

Make `x` global.

"automatic" is the storage type of a variable, not the data type, so it being `int` is orthogonal to it being `static` or `automatic`.

It's a bit surprising your debugger sees an address for the `main`-local `x` at all – it'd be totally appropriate of the compiler to see that `x`, analyze where it's used, see it's used nowhere, and simply don't assign any location at all.

For example:

test_temp_storage.c

```
/* test_temp_storage.c */
int main()
{
  int x;
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

building, with `-Os`, something that every sensible human would do to a microcontroller-targetting compiler (optimizing for code size):

```
$> clang -g -Os -o test test_temp_storage.c
```

debugging, break before entering while loop:

```
$> gdb test
(gdb) break test_temp_storage.c 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400490: file test_temp_storage.c, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/marcus/src/scratch/test 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test_temp_storage.c:5
5     while(1);
(gdb) print x
$1 = <optimized out>
(gdb) print &x
Can't take address of "x" which isn't an lvalue.
```

As you can see, there's no `x` here in existence.

Comment: I am surprised that you see the compiler doesn't assign an address to a local variable (it might be out of scope, but have an address), in ANSI C/C++, and PIC24 C (C for Microchip microcontroller), if that is your case, then how come we can create pointers that can point to an address of a variable

Comment: @Adam see my edit

Comment: @Adam -- if you create a pointer to `x` you have to take the address of `x`, and when you do that, the compiler won't optimize it out.

Comment: @Adam -- that's because if there are no addresses taken of `x`, the compiler can allocate it into a CPU register instead

Answer (score 6):

To understand *why* you cannot assign the address of an 'automatic' local variable, consider recursion.

```
int treesum(const tree *x)
{
    int sum = x->value;
    if (x->left)
        sum += treesum(x->left);
    if (x->right)
        sum += treesum(x->right);
    return sum;
}
```

Each recursive invocation of `treesum` must have its *own copy* of the variable `sum`.  Therefore, they cannot all be assigned the same address.

The rule applies to *all* automatic variables, not just automatic variables in functions called recursively, because the compiler doesn't always know whether a function is going to be called recursively; it could be that f calls g calls h calls f, and h is defined in another source file.